# VS2010 can't debug, breakpoints are never hit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, visual-studio-debugging

My Excel AddIn was targeted to .NET 35 SP1, I just changed it to target .NET 4. Now I am not able to debug b/c breakpoints never get stopped. I can set breakpoints, but debugger never stops at any breakpoint. I check that all projects are in Debug configuration. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume because it is an Add In, that you are attaching to the process, rather than the run/debug method?

If this is true, and you are attaching to the process make sure that you are attaching using Managed (v4.0), instead of Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0). Debug->Attach to Process->Attach to:

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that your AddIn has been disabled in the registry or isn't being loaded. Check the Add-Ins window to see your plugins status.

Comment: No, My addIn is loaded and run fine in Excel. Then I "Attach to Process" attach Excel.Exe to VS2010, I used to be able to debug. But now, I can see my breakpoints with red solid circle in front but they are never hit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the build configuration is set to `Active(Debug)` or `Debug` under the build tab of the properties window.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I checked, all projects in the solution are all Active(Debug)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the screen shown for Debug, click the Advanced button on the lower right of that screen, make sure Debug Info is NOT "none".  In other words, make sure the PDB is generated.